# Explode tessellation shader textureCube drawing not real texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, fragment-shader

I want to make explode effect like this (http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_modifier_tessellation), but for cube with panorama textures (cube with 6 images).

I transform vertex shader to this:

```
uniform float amplitude;

            attribute float displacement;

            varying vec3 vNormal;
            varying vec2 vUv;

            void main() {

                vNormal = normal;
                vUv = ( 0.5 + amplitude ) * uv + vec2( amplitude );

                vec3 newPosition = position + amplitude * normal * vec3( displacement );
                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( newPosition, 1.0 );

            }
```

and fragment to this by adding samplerCube and textureCube:

```
varying vec3 vNormal;
            varying vec2 vUv;

            uniform samplerCube texture1;

            void main() {
                vec3 light = vec3( 0.5, 0.2, 1.0 );
                light = normalize( light );

                float dProd = dot( vNormal, light ) * 0.5 + 0.5;

                gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( dProd ), 1.0 );
                gl_FragColor = textureCube(texture1, vNormal);

            }
```

But result doesn't looks good, it's shows color, but not real detailed texture (look texture http://pg2.paraplan.io/_pano/cube/1024/nx.jpg).

Can you help me with shader setting, or may be know how to do explode tessellation without shaders?

**DEMO: http://pg2.paraplan.io/_pano/cube/scene.html**

Comment: why are you setting `gl_FragColor` twice? Your second `gl_FragColor` is overriding the first

Comment: You're right! But only last line handles texture? i think problem in the lights

Comment: I think the problem is probably UV coordinates